# Configuring JBoss AS 7.1.1 with Mojarra 2.0.4 issues

Tags: jsf-2, jboss7.x, mojarra

I have a working webapp on JBoss AS 5.1.0 GA. Which uses Mojarra 2.0.4 jars. I'm in a process of migrating this on to JBoss AS 7.1.1. This version of JBoss is shipped with 2.1.7. So I downgraded the Mojarra version by defining slots for 2.0.4 and referring to them as dependency in the `META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml` along with other dependencies.

**jboss-deployment-structure.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
          <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="main"/>
          <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="main"/>
          <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="1.2"/>
          <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="1.2"/>          
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
          <module name="org.hibernate.validator" export="true"/>
          <module name="javax.validation.api" export="true"/>
          <module name="com.google.gson" export="true"/>
          <module name="org.codehaus.jettison" export="true"/>
          <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" export="true"/>
          <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" export="true"/>
          <module name="org.apache.log4j" export="true"/>
          <module name="org.jboss.as.web" slot="main" export="true"/>
          <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="2.0.4" export="true"/>
          <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="2.0.4" export="true"/>       
        </dependencies>
  </deployment>   
 </jboss-deployment-structure>
```

This caused the following exception to be thrown at deployment

```
12:51:18,761 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-3) Initializing Mojarra 2.0.4 (FCS b09) for context ''
12:51:20,355 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-3) Unsanitized stacktrace from failed start...: javax.faces.FacesException: Class org.jboss.as.web.deployment.jsf.JandexAnnotationProvider is not an instance of com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProvider
```

To which I referred to [this](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-2656) link and modified my dependencies as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
  <deployment>
        <exclusions>
          <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="main"/>
          <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="main"/>
          <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="1.2"/>
          <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="1.2"/>
          <module name="org.jboss.as.web" slot="main" />
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
          <module name="org.hibernate.validator" export="true"/>
          <module name="javax.validation.api" export="true"/>
          <module name="com.google.gson" export="true"/>
          <module name="org.codehaus.jettison" export="true"/>
          <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" export="true"/>
          <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" export="true"/>
          <module name="org.apache.log4j" export="true"/>
          <module name="org.jboss.as.web" slot="main" export="true"/>
          <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="2.0.4" export="true"/>
          <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="2.0.4" export="true"/>
          <module name="org.jboss.as.web" slot="main">
          <imports>
            <include path="/org/**" />
            <exclude path="/META-INF/**" />
          </imports>
          </module>
        </dependencies>
  </deployment>   
 </jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Which got rid of the error at deployment but introduced the following runtime exception

```
12:59:19,434 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source
12:59:19,435 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)  at java.util.EventObject.<init>(EventObject.java:38)
12:59:19,436 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)  at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.<init>(SystemEvent.java:71)
12:59:19,444 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)  at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.<init>(ComponentSystemEvent.java:73)
```

and

```
12:59:19,489 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/].[Faces Servlet]] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4) Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.createPartialResponseWriter(PartialViewContextImpl.java:431) [jsf-impl.jar:2.0.4-b09]
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.access$300(PartialViewContextImpl.java:72) [jsf-impl.jar:2.0.4-b09]
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$DelayedInitPartialResponseWriter.getWrapped(PartialViewContextImpl.java:559) [jsf-impl.jar:2.0.4-b09]
```

I figured (by googling, of course) that the exception is often caused by three things

1. Invalid/unclosed tags used in xhtml (a wrongly propagated exception)
2. Session timeout (a wrongly propagated exception)
3. Limit on no of POST parameters in Tomcat

Unfortunately, first two were not the causes. I ran my erroneous xhtml pages through validators and found that markup was valid, neither was my session had expired. I also increased the `org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT` to 5000 in `standalone.xml` to address the third point. The error still persists.

I also tried migrating to the default bundled Mojarra 2.7.1 version. That prevented the first runtime exception but the second one remained. 
The only peculiar thing about those pages causing this error is they have ajax calls in them.
Funny enough, the application is working fine with AS 5.1.0 GA, so if my markup is erroneous, it would have given me a difficult time on 5.1.0 as well, which it didn't. So invalid markup is unlikely.
Any pointers much appreciated!

**UPDATE**: Just found out that line at `PartialViewContextImpl.java:431` shows that the `ctx.getRenderKit()` is evaluating to `null`. No idea *why* though

**UPDATE2**: It turns out that the problem is seen only if I use pure html input components within the form i.e. `<input type="text">, <select>` etc. If I remove those from the `<h:form>` or I convert them into corresponding JSF tags, it works fine. Something is going terribly wrong somewhere. I'm not able to figure out excatly if this is caused by jboss, Mojarra or specifically my app. I tried it with a plain vanilla JSF app and it had no errors whether or not I use html input tags. So its the combination of my app and jboss 7.x that is causing this. Any ideas?

Comment: Both exceptions have the same root cause: there's no `UIViewRoot` at all. Assuming that it occurs on POST only, restoring the view from session has apparently failed. I'm not sure, but it's theoretically possible that the particular JBoss 7 instance has a different session management mechanism which would serialize the sessions. Do all your view scoped beans implement `Serializable`? Try testing with state saving method set to `client`, it should produce warnings in logs for classes which do not implement serializable but should do.

Comment: @BalusC: Hmmm.. Yes my view scoped beans do implement `Serializable`. I also had had tried setting state saving method to `client`. I tried it yet again now, but it does not solve it!

Comment: @BalusC: I have a number of context params set in `web.xml` which might be conflicting..? Please have a look http://pastebin.com/5Z5e9usd

Comment: The `com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession` is extremely low with 1. The default is 15. That should however only cause trouble when then enduser opens the same page in multiple browser tabs. With the value of 1, the same page in any previously opened tab get immediately expired.

Comment: @BalusC: I kept is so low because the whole application has only two pages to navigate to. So I only needed 1 previous page's state to be kept in memory. Is it still too low? And Could it screw the view restoration?

Comment: @BalusC: Tried restoring it to 15, didn't affect the exception!

Comment: @BalusC: I updated my question with some findings (UPDATE2). Can you help?

Comment: Sorry, I do not recognize the problem. I am also not really familiar with administering JBoss 7. By best guess would be that the JBoss JSF deployer is somewhat messed up. Does it work fine on a fresh JBoss 7 setup without the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` and any changes in deployers?

Comment: @BalusC: Found the culprit! Answered below. Thanks a lot for your support! :)

Comment: Wow. But why would you have input elements without a name? How are they useful?

Comment: Mostly for using with jQuery plugins. eg: For autocomplete all I needed was `<input id="txtAddFooType" type="text"></input>        <h:inputHidden        id="hdAddFooTypeId"         value="#{fooBean.foo.typeId}"        required="true"        requiredMessage="#{err_msg.required}"/>`. Wherein I applied jQuery UI autocomplete plugin on the input and set the hidden field's value on selection of a suggestion displayed. I didn't need a name attribute in the input at all!

Comment: If the vanilla app doesn't have the problem, but the real app does: step by step remove stuff from your real app until it's equal to the vanilla app. Somewhere along the way you should find the root cause.

Comment: Hmmm..Will do that, but its gonna take a hell lotta time and patience! o_O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally! The issue was related to a bug in Mojarra 2.1.7 as reported [here](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2376)

The Solution is to give a **name** attribute to every pure html component included in `<h:form>`. The part that I could not understand that this bug seems to be related to Mojarra 2.1.7. And the jars I configured for my app were 2.0.4 version, yet the error was seen.

Comment: Interesting. The issue got closed though with a "just use a name attribute" as the solution. I wonder whether it shouldn't be actually fixed instead.

Comment: IMHO, It should be fixed. In my case, I really don't need a name attribute! I'm adding it just for the sake of making it work.

Comment: Moreover, I use jQuery plugins (mine and third party) which generate input and select elements at client side. Now I have to make sure even *they* have a name attribute! -_-